# An issue with calling w.stc.StyledTextCtrl.SaveFile with a unicode content

Tags: unicode, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxstyledtextctrl

I have a wxPython GUI with a wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl text editor. It is possible that its content contain some unicode characters such as Greek letters. I have noticed that StyledTextCtrl.SaveFile() method works only when the content has no unicode characters. Otherwise the saved file ends up being an empty file.

I tried calling StyledTextCtrl.SetCodePage(stc.STC_CP_UTF8) but it did not help either. So, I am not quite sure whether there is a bug in the StyledTextCtrl code, or that I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is very possible that there is a bug. I did not test this one (I would just get the text and save it myself), but I got problems with methods needing position in text like `StartStyling`. It counts bytes instead of characters. Imagine the mess with UTF-8 text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving code uses `wxConvCurrent`, so you could try setting it to `wxConvUTF8` to ensure that UTF-8 is used even when it's not the encoding of the current locale (which is never the case under Windows).

Unfortunately I'm not sure if you can change `wxConvCurrent` from Python. If you can't, the simplest solution would probably be to just write `wxStyledTextCtrl::GetValue()` to a file yourself instead of relying on its `SaveFile()` method. Don't forget to call `SetSavePoint()` after saving successfully if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I decided to write my own Save/Load methods, and calling SetSavePoint() after both those calls made it all work at the end.